# replace special characters in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file, more than 60 pages.
There are many quotations "~~~(text)" in this file and I need to replace these with 「~~~(text)」.
I could not do it with "replace all" functions because two "" is the same.
Is there any way （VBA code, for example) that helps me to replace all "~~~(text)"with 「~~~(text)」
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the text inside the quotation is written in Japanese.

Comment: So is your expecting result would be like this: `「The title is 本日」`?  And what you are trying to do is to remove the double quotes and cover the whole text in `「」`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use MID function to remove the first and last character then append the first and last character with "「" and "」"

Excel Formula:

```
 ="「"& MID(A7,2,LEN(A7)-2) & "」"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try your answer but it did not work. The quotation did not just appear at the beginning and at the end of the cell. For example, the text A7 cell is: The title is "本日”. If I use the MID function, I will get the result is: 「The title is "本日」.

Comment: Hi, you didn't specify the format of data that would be in the cell. There was no mention of "The title is...."

Comment: Hi Keenlearner, yes, I should mention the format of data in the first post. I am sorry for taking your time.